# Will resolve in promise loop break loop iteration?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I make a call to async function in a loop like this (something like upload list of files):

```
return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) { 
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    let response = await myAsyncFunction();
    if (response.ok === false) {
      resolve({error: "Something goes wrong"});
      // break; - is this required?
    }
  }
}
async function myAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
     resolve code....
  }
}
```

If in a loop which is also in a promise I call `resolve()` will loop continue to iterate or it will stop there.
Basically do I need to call `break;` in loop if I resolve before that?

Comment: Why would you return a `Promise` from an `async` function? [`async` returns a promise by default, so you can code it just like a normal function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will resolve in promise loop break loop iteration?

No, it will not. If you want to break the loop, you have to do that with `break` or `return`.

But as a separate thing, there are a couple of other problems there:

1. There's no reason for `new Promise` in that code. `async` functions return promises, no need to wrap them.
2. Using an error flag with resolution is generally not best practice. Use *rejection* to signal failure, not *fulfillment* with an error code.

So:

```
return (async function(resolve, reject) { 
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    let response = await myAsyncFunction();
    if (response.ok === false) { // I'd use `if (!response.ok) {`
      throw new Error("something goes wrong");
    }
  }
  // Presumably return something here
})();
```

(That looks a bit awkward. If you provide more context, it may be possible to make it look less awkward.)

Similarly, `myAsyncFunction` either A) Shouldn't be an `async` function, or B) Shouldn't use `new Promise`. See [*What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Finally, this is suspect:

```
let response = await myAsyncFunction();
if (response.ok === false) { // I'd use `if (!response.ok) {`
  throw new Error("something goes wrong");
}
```

Unless there's a **very** good reason, `myAsyncFunction` should reject, not fulfill, its promise when there's a problem. (The hundreds of thousands of examples of incorrect code using `fetch` without checking `response.ok` is testament to that.)

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing to my bad understand of this. I am trying to refactor my code now. So if you can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208718/when-return-from-awaited-async-function-i-am-getting-undefined

Answer (score 1):

Resolve will break loop or even nested loops, as I see from this code:

```js
function loops() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (j === 1) {
          resolve("first");
        }

        if (j === 5) {
          resolve("second");
        }
      }
    }
    resolve("third");
  });
}

async function execute() {
  let test = await loops();
  console.log(test);
}

execute();
```

Comment: Its important to provide a clear statement of your question.  See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Promise constructors & `async function`s at the same time. That will only cause headaches like this one. Just use an async function, then it becomes clear that you can actually just `return`:

```
 return (async function() { // IIFE is all you need, will result in a Promise itself
   for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
     let response = await myAsyncFunction();
     if (response.ok === false) {
       return {error: "Something goes wrong"};
     }
   }
})();
```

[Read on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)